# Dynamic making input-tag readonly

Tags: html, jsf, twitter-bootstrap-3, jstl, apache-tomee

At this moment I use Tomahawk20 (v1.1.14) in Tomee (v1.7.4) for my input fields in the form:

```
<t:inputText id="email" value="#{bean.klant.email}" maxlength="255" size="50" readonly="#{bean.aktie.readonly}" />
```

The `#{bean.aktie.readonly}` returns *true* or *false*. Tomahawk takes care of the setting of the readonly attribute.

Now I want to change to *bootstrap.js*. Here I can use the normal `<input />` tag but the setting of the readonly causes me trouble. I searched the internet but could not find a solution. On one site they proposed to use a ternary test (`${bean.aktie.readonly?'readonly':''}`):

```
<input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" value="#{bean.klant.email}" maxlength="255" size="50" ${bean.aktie.readonly?'readonly="readonly":''} />
```

This however gives me the error:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /viewMetadata/bean/detail.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 99] Element type "input" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: Your input tag is invalid in many ways... Search the internet for comparable errors... And the answer below is also right. It will never work unless your intention is to totally drop jsf. But if you don't, try jsf passtrough (html5 friendly things) or bootsfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input>` is not a JSF tag, which is what the problem is. You must use `h:inputText` http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_inputtext_tag.htm

You're also missing some quotations. Try this:

```
<h:inputText id="email" styleClass ="form-control" value="#{bean.klant.email}" maxlength="255" size="50" disabled="${bean.aktie.readonly}" />
```

By the way, if you're interested in using Bootstrap with JSF, take a look at: http://www.bootsfaces.net It'll make it incredibly simple to write BootStrap pages that look awesome.

## EDIT

Be sure to see the first comment, you may be able to do this a different way

Comment: No, you **can** use a plain input text... read the links google shows here: https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+friendly+jsf+tags. That is especially done so combining with bootstrap or other javascript ui frameworks would be possible

Comment: As a quick solution I will use the `styleClass` attribute. Stupid of me not seeing this in the documentation. I will look into the *bootsfaces* later. @Kukeltje Thanks for the google search hint. Always difficult to specify what you really search for.